# My homemade sourdough bread tastes bitter after letting it stay for one day

Tags: baking, bread, sourdough, sourdough-starter

I do sourdough bread at home, and through the process, I've tasted lots of not-yet-baked breads. Also, tasted someone else's sourdough bread, which was quite good.

Now, I'm in the stage where I can properly prepare the dough, knead it, and baked it enough so that at the end, I get a good baked bread with a lovely crust, see my latest bread in [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/146251830@N06/46634709922/in/dateposted-public/), and [its inside](https://www.flickr.com/photos/146251830@N06/46634772622/in/dateposted-public/)

However, after cutting the bread, and waiting it for a day or so, the inner side of it tastes like as if it unbaked; it has a bitter taste like half baked dough. What is the reason for that ? After cutting it, I wrap a towel  around it so that is doesn't lose it moisture, which in general does not help much for some reason.

I'm using mostly - around %90 - strong white flour, and corn flour with whole wheat sourdough starter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88253/discussion-on-question-by-onurcanbektas-my-homemade-sourdough-bread-tastes-bitte).